# Trouble with load Lift package

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

When I try load Lift package through emacs-slime.

```
(load "/home/user/lib/lift")
```

I catch the next error

```
; compiling (LOAD "/home/user/lib/lift");; swank:close-connection: encoding error on stream
                       #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM
                         for "socket 127.0.0.1:36328, peer: 127.0.0.1:59724"
                         {1003D9F5E1}>
                       (:EXTERNAL-FORMAT :LATIN-1):
                         the character with code 1069 cannot be encoded.
```

What wrong and how I can load this package?

Comment: Can you clean up your question title if the question has nothing to do with Eos?

Comment: Sorry, I catch this error with Lift and with Eos. I'm just confused :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CL spec, [`LOAD`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm) is used for loading Common Lisp source or compiled files. I'm guessing that `/home/user/lib/lift` is a directory on your system, and that's why `LOAD` isn't working.

You'll probably have the most luck if you install LIFT using [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/index.html), then load the library like it says in the [LIFT User's Guide](http://common-lisp.net/project/lift/user-guide.html):

```
(in-package #:common-lisp-user)  
(use-package :lift)
```